# R replace observations with data from another dataset

Tags: r, dataset

I apologize in advance for the verboseness.

My dataset contains MID dyads (1800-2001) for example

```
id   cc1 year cap1
4114 2   1994  .
4113 2   1994  .
4113 2   1996  .
```

The other dataset has cap1 score for each county-code year (from 1800-2001) for example

```
cc1 year CINC
2   1816 0.039
2   1817 0.035
2   1818 0.036
```

I would like to use the CINC values from the second dataset to fill in the missing values in the cap1 variable in my data set.

To be clear, I should also add the problem is that can be more than 1 or no MIDs per initiators year. So for example, my data set would have 2680 observations for the cap1 variable. However, the second dataset has 14199 observations.

I search the forum on stackoverflow and consulted with a friend and came up with the following

```
mydata$cap1=mydata1[mydata1$ccode==mydata$cc1 & mydata1$year==mydata$year,]$cinc
```

Where my mydata is my dataset and mydata1 is the second dataset

This error was returned

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "cap1", value = c(0.0396975, 0.0358166,  : 
>     replacement has 3 rows, data has 2680
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In mydata1$ccode == mydata$cc1 :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>
> 2: In mydata1$year == mydata$year :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

edit

---

My dataset

```
    structure(list(idnum = c(4054L, 4186L, 4206L, 4273L, 2589L, 2587L
), cc1 = c(365L, 2L, 640L, 2L, 541L, 630L), cap1 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("idnum", 
"cc1", "cap1"), datalabel = "", time.stamp = "29 Nov 2015 23:36", formats = c("%8.0g", 
"%8.0g", "%9.0g"), types = c(65529L, 65529L, 65527L), val.labels = c("", 
"", ""), var.labels = c("MID ID number", "Initiator country code", 
"Initiator's capabilities"), version = 117L, label.table = list(), expansion.fields = list(), strl = list(), byteorder = "LSF", row.names = 2675:2680, class = "data.frame")
```

Second dataset

```
structure(list(stateabb = structure(c(208L, 208L, 208L, 208L, 
208L, 208L), .Label = c("AAB", "AFG", "ALB", "ALG", "AND", "ANG", 
"ARG", "ARM", "AUH", "AUL", "AUS", "AZE", "BAD", "BAH", "BAR", 
"BAV", "BEL", "BEN", "BFO", "BHM", "BHU", "BLR", "BLZ", "BNG", 
"BOL", "BOS", "BOT", "BRA", "BRU", "BUI", "BUL", "CAM", "CAN", 
"CAO", "CAP", "CDI", "CEN", "CHA", "CHL", "CHN", "COL", "COM", 
"CON", "COS", "CRO", "CUB", "CYP", "CZE", "CZR", "DEN", "DJI", 
"DMA", "DOM", "DRC", "DRV", "ECU", "EGY", "EQG", "ERI", "EST", 
"ETH", "ETM", "FIJ", "FIN", "FRN", "FSM", "GAB", "GAM", "GDR", 
"GFR", "GHA", "GMY", "GNB", "GRC", "GRG", "GRN", "GUA", "GUI", 
"GUY", "HAI", "HAN", "HON", "HSE", "HSG", "HUN", "ICE", "IND", 
"INS", "IRE", "IRN", "IRQ", "ISR", "ITA", "JAM", "JOR", "JPN", 
"KEN", "KIR", "KOR", "KUW", "KYR", "KZK", "LAO", "LAT", "LBR", 
"LEB", "LES", "LIB", "LIE", "LIT", "LUX", "MAA", "MAC", "MAD", 
"MAG", "MAL", "MAS", "MAW", "MEC", "MEX", "MLD", "MLI", "MLT", 
"MNC", "MNG", "MOD", "MON", "MOR", "MSI", "MYA", "MZM", "NAM", 
"NAU", "NEP", "NEW", "NIC", "NIG", "NIR", "NOR", "NTH", "OMA", 
"PAK", "PAL", "PAN", "PAP", "PAR", "PER", "PHI", "PMA", "PNG", 
"POL", "POR", "PRK", "QAT", "ROK", "ROM", "RUS", "RVN", "RWA", 
"SAF", "SAL", "SAU", "SAX", "SEN", "SEY", "SIC", "SIE", "SIN", 
"SKN", "SLO", "SLU", "SLV", "SNM", "SOL", "SOM", "SPN", "SRI", 
"STP", "SUD", "SUR", "SVG", "SWA", "SWD", "SWZ", "SYR", "TAJ", 
"TAW", "TAZ", "THI", "TKM", "TOG", "TON", "TRI", "TUN", "TUR", 
"TUS", "TUV", "UAE", "UGA", "UKG", "UKR", "URU", "USA", "UZB", 
"VAN", "VEN", "WRT", "WSM", "YAR", "YEM", "YPR", "YUG", "ZAM", 
"ZAN", "ZIM"), class = "factor"), ccode = c(990L, 990L, 990L, 
990L, 990L, 990L), year = 2002:2007, irst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), milex = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), milper = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), pec = c(47.0876, 44.54492, 42.7761, 43.50082, 
44.62415, 44.93124), tpop = c(178L, 180L, 182L, 183L, 185L, 187L
), upop = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cinc = c(5.12e-06, 5.08e-06, 
5.05e-06, 5.01e-06, 5.01e-06, 4.99e-06), version = c(4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("stateabb", "ccode", "year", "irst", 
"milex", "milper", "pec", "tpop", "upop", "cinc", "version"), row.names = 14194:14199, class = "data.frame")
```

What I have attempted

```
require(foriegn)
require(readstata13)
mydata=read.dta13("Schultz-Geddes.dta")
mydata1=read.csv("NMC_v4_0-3.csv")
mydata$cap1=mydata1[mydata1$ccode==mydata$cc1 & mydata1$year==mydata$year,]$cinc
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
joined <- mydata %>% 
  left_join(mydata1, c("cc1", "year"))
```

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  

Not exactly sure what you need. I actually don't know what the output would be other than the CINC scores from the second data set populating the cap1 observations for each MID id

Comment: Your first dataset doesn't contain a `year` field, and your second dataset doesn't contain a `cc1` field, so you can't join on those two columns.

Answer (score 1):

You want to join the two datasets together.

```
library(dplyr)
joined <- your_dataset %>% 
  inner_join(the_other_dataset, c("cc1", "year"))
```

(It isn't entirely clear from your question what the contents of the datasets are, so you may need a `left_join` rather than an `inner_join`. You can also use `merge` from base-R.)

Then you can change the `cap1` column to use `CICN` when it is missing

```
joined %>%
  mutate_(cap1 = ~ ifelse(is.na(cap1), CICN, cap1))
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work

    joined <- mydata %>% 
  left_join(mydata1, c("cc1", "year"))

Gave me this error
"Error: cannot join on columns 'cc1' x 'cc1': index out of bounds"

Thank you

Comment: @darwinjoe1831  Time to make your question reproducible.

Comment: @darwinjoe1831  Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33992015/edit) your question.

Comment: @Pascal 
Done. Thank you!

Comment: @darwinjoe1831 This still isn't reproducible, since we don't have `mydata.dta` or `otherdata.csv`.  Please make some dummy data for us.

Comment: @RichieCotton

Okay I hope this works Thank you in advance